# Under what circumstances will this Short-Circuit OR operator return the second definition of this sort function?

Tags: perl

I'm currently tasked with maintaining a Perl codebase, and I ran across a block like this:

```
if ($sorttype == 2) {
    $subsort = ( sub { $a->{key2} <=> $b->{key2} } );
}
elsif ($sorttype == 3) {
    $subsort = ( sub { $a->{key3} <=> $b->{key3} || $a->{defaultKey} <=> $b->{defaultKey} } );
}
elsif ($sorttype == 4) {
    $subsort = ( sub { $b->{defaultKey} <=> $a->{defaultKey} } );
}
elsif ($sorttype == 5) {
    $subsort = ( sub { $b->{key5} cmp $a->{key5} || $a->{defaultKey} <=> $b->{defaultKey} } );
}
```

where the basic pattern appears to be:

```
$subsort = ( sub{keyComparison || defaultComparison} );
```

`$subsort` is called later in this manner:

```
foreach (sort $subsort @dataArray) {
    my $data = $_;
    ...
}
```

I'm not understanding the use of the Short-Circuit OR operator here.
Under what possible circumstances, if any, would `$subsort` be defined by the `defaultComparison`?

As a side question, is there a point to wrapping this in a list context (e.g., in parentheses)?
By which, I mean:

```
$subsort = ( sub{keyComparison || defaultComparison} );

# versus

$subsort = sub{keyComparison || defaultComparison};
```

Note:
If anyone can think of a better title for this question, please edit it (I suspect that if I could think of a better title, my google-fu would not have failed me).

Comment: Re "*is there a point to wrapping this in a list context*", There's no list or list context here. Parens don't create lists; parens just change precedence. They have no effect there.

Comment: The comparison operator returns zero in the case where two values are equal, and the right hand side of the statement applies in this case. It's a fairly standard pattern in Perl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're asking about

```
$a->{key3} <=> $b->{key3} || $a->{defaultKey} <=> $b->{defaultKey}
```

In case there's any doubt, this is parsed as

```
( $a->{key3} <=> $b->{key3} ) || ( $a->{defaultKey} <=> $b->{defaultKey} )
```

Because `||` short circuits, its RHS (`$a->{defaultKey} <=> $b->{defaultKey}`) will only be evaluated if its LHS (`$a->{key3} <=> $b->{key3}`) returns false. So your question boils down to the following:

> *When does `$a->{key3} <=> $b->{key3}` return false?*

`<=>` evaluates to

- -1 if its LHS is numerically less-than its RHS.
- 0 if its LHS is numerically equal to its RHS.
- +1 if its LHS is numerically greater than its RHS.

This means that `$a->{key3} <=> $b->{key3}` evaluates to

- -1 if `$a->{key3} < $b->{key3}`
- 0 if `$a->{key3} == $b->{key3}`
- +1 if `$a->{key3} > $b->{key3}`

Of these three values, only `0` is false. This is the only time when the RHS of the `||` will be evaluated.

This means that `$a->{key3} <=> $b->{key3} || $a->{defaultKey} <=> $b->{defaultKey}` evaluates to

- -1 if `$a->{key3} < $b->{key3}`
- -1 if `$a->{key3} == $b->{key3} && $a->{defaultKey} < $b->{defaultKey}`
- 0 if `$a->{key3} == $b->{key3} && $a->{defaultKey} == $b->{defaultKey}`
- +1 if `$a->{key3} == $b->{key3} && $a->{defaultKey} > $b->{defaultKey}`
- +1 if `$a->{key3} > $b->{key3}`

When used as a `sort` compare function, it causes the items to be sorted by `key3`, with ties broken by `defaultKey`.

```
+------------+------------+
| key3       | defaultKey |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |          1 |
|          1 |          2 |
|          1 |          3 |
|          2 |          1 |
|          2 |          2 |
|          2 |          3 |
|          3 |          1 |
|          3 |          2 |
|          3 |          3 |
+------------+------------+
```